# AudioKit recorder setup with mic crashing with "required condition is false: mixingDest"

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm hoping someone can help me out here. I'm trying to get a basic recording setup, but AudioKit is crashing on me which I'm sure is my fault and I'm not doing something right. Here's my setup. In my `viewDidLoad` I'm configuring AudioKit like so:

```
// Session settings
do {
    AKSettings.bufferLength = .short
    try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .allowBluetoothA2DP)
} catch {
    AKLog("Could not set session category.")
}

AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true

// Setup the microphone
micMixer = AKMixer(mic)
micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)

// Load the test player
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audio1", ofType: ".wav")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
testPlayer = AKPlayer(url: url)
testPlayer?.isLooping = true

// Setup the test mixer
testMixer = AKMixer(testPlayer)

// Pass the output from the player AND the mic into the recorder
recordingMixer = AKMixer(testMixer, micBooster)
recorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: recordingMixer)

// Setup the output mixer - only pass the player NOT the mic
outputMixer = AKMixer(testMixer)

// Pass the output mixer to AudioKit
AudioKit.output = outputMixer

// Start AudioKit
do {
    try AudioKit.start()
} catch {
    print("AudioKit did not start! \(error)")
}
```

The app builds fine, but as soon as I trigger `recorder.record()`, the app crashes with the message:

> required condition is false: mixingDest.

I really don't want to be passing the mic to the speaker output, but I DO want to be recording it.

I want to be able to play a file back via the "testPlayer", hear it through the speaker, and simultaneously be able to record the output from the "testPlayer" and the mic, without passing the mic back out through the speakers.

I'm sure this is doable but I don't know enough about how these things should work to know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help hugely appreciated!!

Answer (score 7):

Ok so after talking with the AudioKit guys I found out the issue was because my recordingMixer was not connected to AudioKit.output. In order to pull audio through a mixer, it needs to be connected to AudioKit.output.

In order to mute the output from my recordingMixer, I had to create a dummy recording mixer that was muted, and passed that through to the outputMixer.

See the updated example below:

```
// Session settings
do {
    AKSettings.bufferLength = .short
    try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .allowBluetoothA2DP)
} catch {
    AKLog("Could not set session category.")
}

AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true

// Setup the microphone
micMixer = AKMixer(mic)
micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)

// Load the test player
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audio1", ofType: ".wav")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
testPlayer = AKPlayer(url: url)
testPlayer?.isLooping = true

// Setup the test mixer
testMixer = AKMixer(testPlayer)

// Pass the output from the player AND the mic into the recorder
recordingMixer = AKMixer(testMixer, micBooster)
recorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: recordingMixer)

// Create a muted mixer for recording audio, so AudioKit will pull audio through the recording Mixer, but not play it through the output.
recordingDummyMixer = AKMixer(recordingMixer)
recordingDummyMixer.volume = 0

outputMixer = AKMixer(testMixer, recordingDummyMixer)

// Pass the output mixer to AudioKit
AudioKit.output = outputMixer

// Start AudioKit
do {
    try AudioKit.start()
} catch {
    print("AudioKit did not start! \(error)")
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: recordingDummyMixer is not needed in my case. outputMixer = AKMixer(testMixer, recordingMixer) works fine

Comment: Thanks Tim, your post was helpful. I had the same problem when replacing an effect AU within a running engine. It is important that the engine finds a path from input all the way to output. So I solved this by first connecting the new effect to a mixer, then connecting the upstream mixer to that effect, and only then disconnecting the old effect.